# How can a module verify one of the update pages is shown?

Tags: 7

What should a module do to verify if Drupal is updating the database tables to avoid to output a message when one of the update pages are being shown (or to avoid to do any superfluous task during the update)?

The module I am referring to is a custom debugging module that does some tests at every requested page, and outputs the result using `drupal_set_message()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

devel.module has a function called `devel_silent()` that does some very comprehensive checking. I might replicate this in your own module.

```
function devel_silent() {
  // isset($_GET['q']) is needed when calling the front page. q is not set.
  // Don't interfere with private files/images.
  return
    function_exists('drupal_is_cli') && drupal_is_cli() ||
    (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ApacheBench') !== FALSE) ||
    !empty($_REQUEST['XDEBUG_PROFILE']) ||
    isset($GLOBALS['devel_shutdown']) ||
    strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'update.php') ||
    (isset($_GET['q']) && (
      in_array($_GET['q'], array( 'admin/content/node-settings/rebuild')) ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('system/files')) == 'system/files' ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('batch')) == 'batch' ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('file/ajax')) == 'file/ajax')
    );
}
```

You can probably simplify this a bit to just the part that is checking for 'update.php' and the `$_GET['q']` checking.

```
    strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'update.php') ||
    (isset($_GET['q']) && (
      in_array($_GET['q'], array( 'admin/content/node-settings/rebuild')) ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('system/files')) == 'system/files' ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('batch')) == 'batch' ||
      substr($_GET['q'], 0, strlen('file/ajax')) == 'file/ajax')
    );
```

Comment: I would also verify the current path doesn't contain `"admin/modules"`; the other paths are probably paths that my module should check too (it doesn't make sense that the module does anything during batch operations).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, check the path. If the path is /admin/update* or whatever, don't run your code. Check out [drupal_get_destination()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination).

Comment: The value returned by `drupal_get_destination()` is an array containing the value of `$_GET['destination']`, in most of the cases; it doesn't contain the path of the currently shown page.